# TypeError: addQuiz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm getting this error and I thought I fulfilled the parameters needed but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and what this error exactly means. I get this error: TypeError: addQuiz() missing 1 required positional argument: 'score'

This is the class that I created for the student:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        self.counter = 0

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def addQuiz(self, score):
        self.score += score
        self.counter += 1

    def get_total_score(self):
        return self.score

    def getAverageScore(self):
        return self.score / self.counter


from Student import Student

x = input("Enter a student's name: ")


while True:

    score = input("Enter in a quiz score (if done, press enter again): ")
    quiz_score = Student.addQuiz(score)
    if len(score) < 1:
        print(Student.getName(x), Student.get_total_score(quiz_score))
        break
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Edit

Those methods are not class methods, are instance method, make an instance, and call them:

Also, taking a better look on it, you had another sort of problem, I will comment:

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.score = 0
        self.counter = 0

    def getName(self):
        return self.name

    def addQuiz(self, score):
        self.score += score
        self.counter += 1

    def get_total_score(self):
        return self.score

    def getAverageScore(self):
        return self.score / self.counter

###execution part (you can put it in a main... but as you want)


name = input("Enter a student's name: ") #create a variable name, and give it to the object you will create
student_you = Student(name) #here, the name as parameter now belongs to the object
score = float(input("Enter in a quiz score (if done, press enter again): ")) #you have to cast the input to a numerical type, such as float

while score > 1: #it is better to the heart of the people to read the code, to modify a "flag variable" to end a while loop, don't ask in a if and then use a break, please, just an advice
    score = float(input("Enter in a quiz score (if done, press enter again): ")) #here again, cast to float the score
    student_you.addQuiz(score) #modify your object with the setter method


print(student_you.getName(), student_you.get_total_score()) #finally when the execution is over, show to the world the result
```

Comment: Thank you for the modifications and the advice. I see what is happening but the problem that I get now (I believe its due to me pressing enter again when I want to end the while loop) is: ValueError: could not convert string to float:

Comment: I'm not sure what to do in order to fix this. Do I need to change everything or is there an easy solution?

Comment: @HoonLee well, if you press the "enter" key, you will send an string, the empty string, "" and that's not a float, you can ugly fix it by adding an if, or an exeption, but I don't know what do you expect if the user write a bad input

Comment: @HoonLee See this question for how to fix that problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response

Comment: @SethMMorton very very nice suggestion, I think in something like that, but I didn't want to add it to the answer because it answer to another question... and it is hard to understand the main question

Comment: @DamianLattenero Yes, that solution does not belong in your answer... it would be answering a whole different question, and it is already answered so well there!

Comment: @HoonLee don't forget to mark the answer as accepted and vote if it was helpful, remember that your original question was answered :).